# Is there any GWT fork around?

Tags: gwt

I know that GWT is open-source and freely available. However just a curious question, is there any GWT fork around? I know one that can be considered which is Vaadin.

Cheers.

Comment: Note that Vaadin is not a fork of GWT, and they are actually very different. GWT is a client side toolkit while Vaadin is a server-side framework that just uses GWT for rendering. Also Vaadin's component set is much richer than GWT's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did already answer your question, but there are others. The first that comes to mind is [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/), which is actually a Python to Javascript compiler.

Comment: "Doing the same as" can hardly be considered a fork IMO.

Comment: @Yann Vernier, I like the  idea of Pyjamas, and I found similar solutions for Java-to-javascript approach like GWT, JWT and Jaxcent...but what I am looking is something that "forked" GWT.

Comment: More of a port than a fork, then. Sorry, I'm not trying hard to keep up with web stuff, as I'm more of an embedded/electronics guy.